# Cron Expression time change for core_email_queue_send_all

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, cron

currently, core_email_queue_send_all cron expression is */1 * * * *

I want to change to */5 * * * *

How can I change the time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create your own extension, make it depend on `Mage_Core` and add this to your `config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <!-- ... rest of your configuration ... -->
    <crontab>
        <jobs>
            <core_email_queue_send_all>
                <schedule><cron_expr>*/5 * * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
            </core_email_queue_send_all>
        </jobs>
    </crontab>
</config>
```

This way you avoid changing core files which is a no-go.

In case you wonder how to make your extension depending on another: here is an example for a fictive extension `Mzeis_Test` (code goes into `app/etc/modules/Mzeis_Test.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mzeis_Test>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Core />
            </depends>
        </Mzeis_Test>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Sending Emails by Queue in Magento 1.9.1](http://www.aschroder.com/2015/01/sending-emails-by-queue-in-magento-1-9-1/)

Email cron setting is defined in

> app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml

```
<core_email_queue_send_all>
     <schedule><cron_expr>*/1 * * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
     <run><model>core/email_queue::send</model></run>
</core_email_queue_send_all>
```

Comment: do not suggest users to change code in the core ;)